# MariaDB - cannot login as root

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to setup MariaDB (10.0.29) on Ubuntu (16.04.02). After I installed it and started the process (`sudo service mysql start`), I cannot login as `root` even though I originally set the password to blank.

Ie `mysql -u root` will deny me access. I logged in through `sudo mysql` and checked the user table, ie. `select user, password, authentication_string from mysql.user` and as expected:

```
+---------+----------+-----------------------+ 
| User    | password | authentication_string |
+---------+----------+-----------------------+
| root    |          |                       |
+---------+----------+-----------------------+
```

I also created a new user, ie. `create user 'test'@'localhost' identified by '';` and when I try to do `mysql -u test` (empty password), it works as expected and logs me in.

The user table looks like this:

```
+---------+----------+-----------------------+
| User    | password | authentication_string |
+---------+----------+-----------------------+
| root    |          |                       |
| test    |          |                       |
+---------+----------+-----------------------+
```

So, can anyone tell me why I cannot login as `root` with empty password but I can login as `test`?

Comment: Empty password and no password might be treated differently.

Comment: I had similar experience. First, on install I had not asked to set root password. I tried to reset root password, but still did not got access. And reinstalled and got into same situation. Also Ubuntu 16.04 64bit. Installed mysql afterwards

Comment: You can reset your root password as mentioned in this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password)

Comment: You can login using `mysql -uroot -p`, when the terminal ask for the password, just press the enter key.

Answer (score 33):

Unlike native MariaDB packages (those provided by MariaDB itself), packages generated by Ubuntu by default have [unix_socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin) authentication for the local root. To check, run

```
SELECT user, host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
```

If you see `unix_socket` in the `plugin` column, that's the reason.

To return to the usual password authentication, run

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = '' WHERE plugin = 'unix_socket';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

(choose the `WHERE` clause which fits your purposes, the one above is just an example)

Comment: This helped.  I understand instead of using 'root' and password, ubuntu forced mariadb to use its own authentication when logged in as root.

Answer (score 6):

The issue you're having is due to changes in the authentication system of MariaDB 10.4:

> As a result of the above changes, the open-for-everyone all-powerful root account is finally gone. (...) because the root account is securely created automatically. They are created as: CREATE USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket OR mysql_native_password USING 'invalid'

<s>**If you really want to access your DB as `root`**, you should login via cli `mariadb -p` and run:</s>

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD("your-password-here");
```

Source: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-from-mariadb-104/#altering-the-user-account-to-revert-to-the-previous-authentication-method

**About the other solution bellow**: they won't work because MariaDB won't also allow you to update the `plugin` column: `ERROR 1348 (HY000): Column 'plugin' is not updatable`.~

---

**Update 2020**: although my solution above works it replaces the default root `unix_socket` authentication with a password. I've noticed this breaks tasks such as mariadb upgrade / your own maintenance scripts that would expect to be able to connect to the DB without extra passwords when running as root.

My suggestion is to **add a new root login** as follows:

```
CREATE USER `root`@`%` IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password using PASSWORD('your-password-here');
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This will effectively **still allow for the default behavior of root login and add external access to the DB using the password**.

Comment: This also enables MariaDB Mac OS root login

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for some time. My Ubuntu comes with MariaDB (10.0.31) by default. After reinstalling a few times and changing the plugins to various suggestions - I still could not login properly to mysql.

In the end I installed the latest MariaDB (10.2.12) from the repo :
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/

I was able to login properly immediately.

Comment: It looks like MariaDB 10.4 changed the behavior to match Debian/Ubuntu:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/