# connect to dockerized sql from host: Access denied

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm sorry to open one more of those 'can't connect to my database' questions, but after searching for hours I just don't get it.

I want a dockerized database to be used by the (non dockerized) invoicePlane app.

So I'm using the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
      image: mariadb:latest 
      #also tried mysql:latest
      restart: always
      environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'invoiceplane_db'
          MYSQL_USER: 'invoiceplane'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'pass1'
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pass0'
      expose:
          - '3306'
      volumes:
          myserver/path:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    invoiceplane-db:
```

It starts with `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`

From inside the container, everything works fine. I can connect, e.g. via `mysql -uroot -ppass0`, and see

```
+--------------+-----------+
| User         | Host      |
+--------------+-----------+
| invoiceplane | %         |
| root         | %         |
| root         | localhost |
+--------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

Now I want to access  the db from the host, trying

```
mysql invoiceplane_db_1:3306 -uroot -ppass0
```

where invoiceplane_db_1 is the container's name.

but I'm always getting:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Through my websearch I gained the impression that this may have to do with the `bind-address` in the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` of the container, which was stated [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/), for example. But I was not able to get it right. Initially, the parameter was commented out. I set it to `bind-address    = 127.0.0.1` and restarted the container. It did not help.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You should map the container port you exposed to a host port

Answer (score 1):

This is my working docker-composer for mariadb:

```
db:
  image: mariadb:10.4
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - db-storage:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root-pass
    MYSQL_USER: my-user
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: my-user-pass
    MYSQL_DATABASE: my-database
```

From the looks of it, seems like you are missing the port mapping: `3306:3306`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did try that. Since port 3306 on host is already in use, I mapped it to 3307, so `- "3307:3306`. The Access denied remains. When I type localhost:3307 to my browser, I get a response, so the connection should be there.

Comment: This is my connection url: `jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/my-database` using `my-user` and `my-user-pass`. Can you try to connect using `invoiceplane` user and password instead of `root`?

Also, checking this link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58040022

Comment: Did I understand this correctly?
I tried `mysql localhost:3307/invoiceplane_db -uinvoiceplane -ppass1`,
I even tried `mysql jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/invoiceplane_db -uinvoiceplane -ppass1`, which I considered unlikely to work.
Still the same: Access denied.